# D and L configuration of monosaccharides

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, molecular-structure, carbonyl-compounds, carbohydrates

I got this question in the last week's test from Organic Chemistry.

I am a bit confused in assigning D and L configuration.
Help me understand the topic of D and L configuration and help with this problem

Question Type : MCQ
[image: Problem]

Comment: You need to rotate C5 into a Fischer conformation that has C6 in the vertical chain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**D and L configuration of sugars:**

Draw the given sugar (aldose) in the Fischer projection with the most oxidized carbon at the top (i.e. aldehyde carbon). If it is a ketose, make the closest terminal carbon to the keto group at the top. Now:

- if the $\ce{OH}$ on the bottom chiral center points to the right hand side, the sugar is referred to as D-sugar.
- if the $\ce{OH}$ on the bottom chiral center points to the left hand side, it is referred to as L-sugar.

To learn some history of this nomenclature, read [this article](https://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2017/05/24/d-and-l-sugars/).

Now look at each of the given compounds:

[image: Sugars]

In (A)-(C) of given compounds, the bottom chiral center is not set to reflect the required $\ce{H-C^*-OH}$ configuration. In order to get the required configuration, you need to switch each group in that chiral center twice as indicated in the image. The gray structures in the middle raw are after first switch (they are gray because, technically, they are epimers of the corresponding structures of first raw) and the bottom raw structures are after the second switch, which are the same as corresponding structures in the first row.

As evident, (A), (C), and (D) have the $\ce{OH}$ on the bottom chiral center points to the right hand side, thus, they are D-sugars. Only (B) has the $\ce{OH}$ on the bottom chiral center points to the left hand side, and thus, it is a L-sugar. Hence, the answer is (B), because it is not a D-sugar.